# Load JSON in AngularJS App (loading google spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, google-sheets

I am trying to load up a Google spreadsheet in my application, but I am not managing to make it work. I've tried different ways of accessing the tree structure (via the controller and/or via the html), but none of them worked.
Any idea what may be wrong?

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('SuperCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1lZWwacSVxTD_ciOsuNsrzeMTNAl0Dj8SOrbaMqPKM7U/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=x")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.items = response;
    });
}]);
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="SuperCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items.feed.entry">
    {{ item.title.type }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First rotate your profile picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

created a working plunkr for you

http://plnkr.co/edit/JfXrVDWacvjF2RzxP18g?p=preview

But here's also the meat of the solution:

```
app.controller('SuperCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1lZWwacSVxTD_ciOsuNsrzeMTNAl0Dj8SOrbaMqPKM7U/od6/public/values?alt=json'
    var parse = function(entry) {
      var category = entry['gsx$category']['$t'];
      var description = entry['gsx$description']['$t'];
      var title = entry['gsx$title']['$t'];
      var url = entry['gsx$url']['$t'];
      var yo = entry['gsx$yo']['$t'];
      return {
        category: category,
        description: description,
        title: title,
        url: url,
        yo: yo
      };
    }
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(response) {
      var entries = response['feed']['entry'];
      $scope.parsedEntries = [];
      for (key in entries) {
        var content = entries[key];
        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));
      }
    });
}]);
```

First problem you were using the 'json in script' version of the API which is complicated and not what you want. Changed the API result to just be JSON.

Second problem is parsing the result, see my function there that converts the confusing google spreadsheet entries into nice readable JSON.

The example works - have a tinker. My advice is find something other than google spreadsheets to store your data.

It's funny, I actually built an app on top of google spreadsheets too (trackerkeeper.co), which is why I could help you. Not super proud of the engineering but it was kind of fun:

Good luck.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. That makes sense. Yes, I'm only using google spreadsheet as a temporary solution. I had never done it and thought it would be fun to try (alas, I failed to figure it out :)).

Comment: The plunkr doesn't seem to work anymore. Would love to see it work again :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a new working plunker. The problem was that it can't find the "yo" variable anymore.

```
var parse = function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
  var category = entry['gsx$category']['$t'];
  var description = entry['gsx$description']['$t'];
  var title = entry['gsx$title']['$t'];
  return {
    category: category,
    description: description,
    title: title,
    url: url
  };
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YwskJRuORJBjw4S9wU7V?p=preview

Comment: I have tried replacing your g-sheet link with mine and entry with mine. No luck.