# Posting to a Google Spreadsheet with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, post, google-sheets

Following on from this post [Load JSON in AngularJS App (loading google spreadsheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057517/load-json-in-angularjs-app-loading-google-spreadsheet) how do i go about posting data from my Angular app to a spreadsheet? Is it even possible to do?

I've created a version of my app that updates an array of data locally but now want to switch to pulling in data from an external source (a google spreadsheet - this works at the moment) and **posting** to this external source as well.

PS only using Google Spreadsheet for quick prototyping.

HTML form, the ng-submit was then being used to update a local array within my controller.

```
<form  name="reviewsForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="newReviewController as newReviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewsForm.$valid && newReviewCtrl.addScore(reviews)" novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="type" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">Review type</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 select-menu">
        <select tabindex="" name="type" id="type" class="validate" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.type"  class="validate" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Review type</option>
            <option ng-repeat="type in types">{{type.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label for="reviewTitle" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">Review title</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input tabindex="" type="text" name="reviewTitle" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.name" class="validate" placeholder="Review title" required>
    </div>                                    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Description" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">Description</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input tabindex="" type="text" name="Description" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.desc" class="validate" placeholder="Description" required >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Image" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">Image url</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input tabindex="" type="text" name="Image" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.imgUrl" class="validate" placeholder="Image url" required >
    </div>
    <label for="info" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">More info url</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input tabindex="" type="text" name="info" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.infoUrl" class="validate" placeholder="More info url" required >
    </div>                                    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date" class="col-xs-4 control-label hide">Date</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input tabindex="" type="date" max="2020-01-01"  min="2015-01-01" name="date" ng-model="newReviewCtrl.reviews.date" class="validate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <button tabindex="" type="submit" class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light green btn-add white-text" ng-show="reviewsForm.$valid" ng-click="newReviewCtrl.reviews.type='0'" id="add-submit" style="margin:0px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#addReviewCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="addReviewCollapse">
            Add
        </button>   
    </div>        
</div>
```

Example of part of the existing array of data

```
$scope.reviews = [
    {
        name: "The Force Awakens",
        imgUrl: 'img/theforceawakens.jpg',
        type:'Movie',
        desc: 'Amazeballs',
        infoUrl: '???',  
        date: new Date(2016, 02, 16, 16)
    },
```

I've put all the same information in to a google spreadsheet and am using this post to pull that data in to my page [Load JSON in AngularJS App (loading google spreadsheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057517/load-json-in-angularjs-app-loading-google-spreadsheet) , i now want to post to that spreadhseet as well using the above form but dont know where to start.

Comment: Please, add your code to see more context

Comment: Please share your solution if you were able to post data to google spreadsheet using AngularJS.