# How to POST / GET data from a google sheet via requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-sheets-api

After I successfuly completed the [google-sheets-api quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs) I ended up with the conclusion I have to run **node quickstart.js** in order to POST (write) data into my google-sheet. Is it possible to make requests using for example $http.post / get  from AngularJS or $ajax ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load JSON in AngularJS App (loading google spreadsheet)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057517/load-json-in-angularjs-app-loading-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: Yea, thank you very much sir !!